# Antenna gain and TX Power

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I have a question: Let's say I take antenna with 27 dBm TX Power, but the signal level at the RX is less than -97dBm (that's bad isn't it?). Is it ok to put some antenna gain (as example: 27dBi)? Then I get like -60dBm RX signal level.

Comment: "_Is it ok to put some antenna gain?_" That really depends on the laws in your country. In the U.S., the FCC sets limits on antenna gain.

Comment: I understand that. But I have read few articles and there are very different opinions about putting antena gain... Someone wrote that the sum of tx power and antenna gain has to be 20??? (What the hell?) Does that depends on law too?

Comment: That actually depends on the frequency used. You really need to do some research on what is allowed for the frequency you want to use. There is also a difference if it is point-to-multipoint or point-to-point. https://www.scc-ares-races.org/mesh/doc/WiFi_Part_15_Power_Limits_v150424.pdf

Comment: It's a point to point and the frequency is 5800Mhz. Im learning a new thing, that's why i have questions like this. I'm using a simulator to test things. Just want to know if it's good or bad.

Comment: When you "put some antenna gain," are you using a different antenna or are you using an amplifier?